# Cloud Init on Google Compute Engine (GCE) with Centos7/8 doesn't run properly on First boot, but fine after any other reboot

Tags: centos, google-compute-engine, cloud-init

We have a CentOS 8 (tried 7 as well) image and I am adding some config to act as a router.

The issue is, for some reason, the first time the instance is created, cloud init doesn't read the network config we pass using the user-data metadata

```
#cloud-config
network
  version: 1
  etc...
```

We configure eth1 to use dhcp and get cloud-init to manage it, as well as add a route.

Works perfectly every time after the initial boot up (and stop>start again).

To me it feels like cloud-init is not aware of the config, but when I go in the machine and do `cloud-init query userdata` i can see the data, and even then if I do `cloud-init clean && cloud-init init` it doesn't do anything. The same commands work fine if the machine was rebooted

Answer (score 0):

Try running `cloud-init analyze show` both times (instance creation and consecutive reboot) and check for any  differences.

Sadly, cloud providers kind-of abuse the abilities of `cloud-init`, not to a complete fault. `cloud-init` allows for customization of vendor/user provided configuration (who overrides what), changing the order of boot stages, etc.
This is done mostly because different cloud  providers need network/provisioning/storage at different times. For example, AWS attaches storage after network (EBS only), Azure provides VM only after storage is attached and it's natively provided as NTFS (they really format the drive if you need anything else), etc.

These shenanigans, while understandable (datacenter infrastructure defines user availability) make `cloud-init`'s documentation merely a suggestion for the user to  investigate.

From my experience, Azure is  the closest to original implementation. Possibly they haven't learned yet how to  utilize the potential in their  favor.

My general  suggestion for any instance customization (almost always works) is to write a  script with `write_files` and execute them with `bootcmd/runcmd`, because these run at the `final` stage, and provide for best override opportunity. Edit `hosts`, change firewall rules - most of the stuff will not  require reboot.